# Can't get the selected overlay values individually

Tags: android, google-maps, android-alertdialog, alerts

I am working with a Google map oriented android project now i got a problem in this class i class i used certain overlay to mark nearest places when we touch on particular overlay it will show an alert-box contains name and reference now i am retrieve the reference using the getsnipet() method now i don't want to display the alert-dialog box but when i disable that thing i cannot get the reference can anyone help me to fix this error and here is my code...

```
public class PlacesMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    // Nearest places
    PlacesList nearPlaces;

    // Map view
    MapView mapView;

    // Map overlay items
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

    GeoPoint geoPoint;
    // Map controllers
    MapController mc;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    OverlayItem overlayitem;

    String p_u_name;
    Place reference;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

        // Getting intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        p_u_name=i.getStringExtra("p_u_name");
        reference = (Place) i.getSerializableExtra("place_reference");


        i.putExtra("p_u_name",p_u_name);



        // Users current geo location
        String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
        String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");

        System.out.println("sarath"+user_latitude + user_longitude);

        // Nearplaces list
        nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        // Geopoint to place on map
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude) * 1E6),
                (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude) * 1E6));

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

        // Map overlay item
        overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
                "That is you!");

        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

        // Drawable marker icon
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

        itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

        mc = mapView.getController();

        // These values are used to get map boundary area
        // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
        int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        // check for null in case it is null
        if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
            // loop through all the places
            for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
                latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
                longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

                // Geopoint to place on map
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                        (int) (longitude * 1E6));
                String s = place.formatted_address;
                String p = place.formatted_phone_number;
                String n = s;
                System.out.println("sarath"+s);



                // Map overlay item
                                 //Here it passes the selected overlay name and reference to the alerdialog box 
                overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint,place.name,place.reference);

                i.putExtra("place_reference", place.reference);

//              System.out.println("this is mapactivity and reference is:"+ab);

                itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);



                // calculating map boundary area
                minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
                minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
                maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
                maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
            }
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            // showing all overlay items
            itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
        }

        // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
        mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

        // Showing the center of the map
        mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
        mapView.postInvalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not about the Google Maps API V3. ( tag removed )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is pretty unclear... I think by 'reference' you mean 'description', in which case you were correct in using `getsnippet()`.  If you've already seen the `String` through an `AlertDialog`, then taking out the dialog should not prevent you from seeing the snippet.  Could you give us a bit more on your precise issue?